# How to create a colored sphere

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d, matplotlib-3d

I have a data set which maps a tuple of phi and theta to
a value which represents the strength of the signal.
I want to plot these on a sphere. I simply followed
a demo from matplotlib and adjusted the code to my
use case.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

u = phi
v = theta
vals =vals/vals.max()
Map = cm.coolwarm
facecolors = Map(vals[:])

x = 10 * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))

y = 10 * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))

z = 10 * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))

ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False, facecolors=facecolors)

plt.show()
```

This generates an error message IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4. I also looked into the source code, which seems
to indicate to me that facecolors isn't formatted correctly, but I'm
struggling to figure out, what formatting is needed exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your question is: "How to get rid of this IndexError?", I modified your code and now it works. `plot_surface` takes X,Y,Z and facecolors as 2D arrays of corresponding **values on a 2D grid**. Facecolors in your case weren't and this was the source of your error.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm, colors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

u, v = np.mgrid[0:np.pi:50j, 0:2*np.pi:50j]

strength = u
norm=colors.Normalize(vmin = np.min(strength),
                      vmax = np.max(strength), clip = False)

x = 10 * np.sin(u) * np.cos(v)
y = 10 * np.sin(u) * np.sin(v)
z = 10 * np.cos(u)

ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False,
                       facecolors=cm.coolwarm(norm(strength)))

plt.show()
```

[image]

However, if your data is **not on a 2D grid** you are in trouble. Additionally if your grid is not regular the sphere you plot will look irregular as well. So if your question is: "*How to plot a heatmap on a sphere?*", there is already such a question and solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22128909/plotting-the-temperature-distribution-on-a-sphere-with-python) using `Basemap` package produces this result:

[image]